# Compare variable with integer in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

I have an if statement I need to run, as long as the value I have stored in my `$counter` variable is greater than `5`.

Here is the respective section of my current (non-functioning) script:

```
if $counter > 5
then
    echo "something"
fi
```

The mistake I'm making is probably very obvious, but for some reason I couldn't find the solution online..
Thanks!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well that is quite simple:

```
if [ "$counter" -gt 5 ]
then
    echo "something"
fi
```

Comment: Unless you need `sh` compatibility, it's better to use `[[` and `]]` instead of `[` and `]`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

Comment: Of course. It's meant for compatibility seeing that he didn't mention bash in the title.

Comment: @konsolebox, you need to look at the tags below the question. Titles are very often misleading.

Comment: @glennjackman yeah i just noticed the tags :)

Comment: If you're using `bash`, `(( counter > 5 ))` is even better.

Comment: @chepner I disagree: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18568726/445221

Comment: @glennjackman I'm actually not sure if everyone who tags `bash` knows the difference between `bash` and simply `sh`.  (Commenting for reference).

Comment: Upvoting this in 2021 exactly because I was looking for a portable syntax.

Answer (score 26):

Arithmetic needs to be done between `((` and `))`:

```
if (( $counter > 5 ))
```

Incidentally, you can also leave off the `$` in arithmetic, though it doesn't hurt to keep it.

Comment: Yes however, I would argue conditional expressions should be done in `[[ ]]`.  So which one should really be it?  I'd pick `[[ ]]`.  See my arguments here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18568726/445221.  (Commenting for reference).