# how to use "<=,>=" in bash command "[[ ]]"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command

I'm a newbie of bash. When I try to use the command `[[` for compare, I encounter the problem as below:

[image]

```
[root@JD ~]# [[ 2 <= 2 ]]
-bash: syntax error in conditional expression
-bash: syntax error near `2'
```

From my tutorial book, `[ 2 -le 2 ]` should be equal to `[[ 2 <= 2 ]]`, I don't know  the reason why it's a syntax error.

Comment: Please replace image with text.

Comment: Particularly if you are just learning bash and therefore expect to make mistakes, I'd strongly recommend that you avoid doing everything as root, since without protection your mistakes could be a lot more serious. (I'd make the same suggestion to an experienced user, but I suspect most experienced users have already learned this lesson, possibly the hard way.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing numbers in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18668556/608639), [Comparing integers: arithmetic expression or conditional expression](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278707/56041), [Compare variable with integer in shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18133161/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

In double square brackets, `<=` is not a recognised operator. `<` and `>` are used to compare strings, anyway. Use `-le` for numbers, or switch to arithmetic expression, which uses round parentheses:

```
(( 5 <= 10 ))
```